# How do you format a file without the excepted extension in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

**Context:**

I have data saved to files without extensions.  These files map to http urls but are on the filesystem and are used as cache.  ie `http://server.com/calendar/data`  would have a corresponding file at `/tmp/calendar/data`.  So it's important that I keep the file names as is.

When I open the file `data` which is a json file in PyCharm I can't `Reformat Code` and have it human readable.

Is there a way to format files that are json ad hoc in PyCharm?  Is it possible to choose the formatter in PyCharm as opposed to having the extension dictate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You right click on the file, then you click `Override File Type` and then you choose `JSON`.

[image]

By following the aforementioned steps, the `Reformat Code` option is activated:

[image]